# /bin/sh: TexturePacker: command not found (while zsh works) macOS Monterey

Tags: bash, shell, script, zsh

I have a small Adobe Animate extension that uses TexturePacker to pack sprites onto sprite sheets. I've successfully added TexturePacker to $PATH (/Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS) so it works from Terminal (zsh). Is there any way to make it work from within my extension that uses /bin/sh? 
[/bin/sh error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Fd5.png)

Originally $PATH looks like the following: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
.zshrc: `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS`
.profile, .bashrc and .bash_profile all contain the same export as .zshrc.

Comment: please edit your question to contain the .profile or .zshrc or wherever at login that your PATH gets set.

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Potential diagnosis of type of shell:**
Please check to see what your setting for `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options > Network Account Server: Join... > Open Directory Utility... > Directory Editor > [yourAccountUserNameHere] > UserShell`

Perhaps it is `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/zsh` or `/bin/bash`.  Perhaps applications such as Adobe Animate are using this shell instead of zsh or bash that you are using interactively downstream post-login.  Perhaps PATH is set correctly only in zsh and in bash but not in sh due to sh being the shell invoked by default at login.

**Related corrective action:**
As a general rule (practically independent of the potential situation with logging in via /bin/sh that I suspect above), PATH should always be set  & exported fully in .profile instead of incrementally by appending in each subshell so that several subshells deep, you don't end up with, say, `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS:/Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS:/Applications/TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS` needlessly bloating the search time along PATH by the same directory appearing more than once.  Conversely, things that should be done in .zshrc, .kshrc, .cshrc, and/or .bashrc are the things that aren't inherited from the parent invoking shell, such as aliases, context-sensitive command-line prompts that use each shell's nonportable/nonPOSIX syntax for additional features, setopt options for that shell, keybindings, etc.

**TL;DR:** Put your PATH assignment entirely in `~/.profile` instead of appending PATH in the `~/.*rc` files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've also added a link to TexturePacker exec file to usr/local/bin, so it should be callable from any location. Still, this doesn't work inside my Adobe Animate extension. My only guess is that extensions are run inside some kind of sandbox?